# SQL Replace fixed length, different numeric values within TEXT column

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, sql-server-2008-r2, wildcard

I have been busy for 2 full days finding a solution for my problem. I have a large database and I want to replace a set of numbers within a column.

The column contains text and within that text it has this format `FPC1234567890`. 
The only thing is: the numbers are always different (but always 10 in length), the 3 letters are always the same.

I tried this:

```
update [tablename] 
SET columnname = 
    CAST(REPLACE(CAST(columnname as NVarchar(4000)), 
    'FPC[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', 'newclientnumber') AS NText)
```

This does not work, as the wildcards do not work with the replace function, it does work when I type in one of the correct numbers residing in the column.

I can find what I need to update with this:

```
SELECT * FROM Tablename
WHERE columnname LIKE '%FPC[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (sql-server perhaps?)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has a function [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql) that looks for a given pattern similar to `LIKE`. If your `text` column can contain only one instance of this pattern (not multiple), then you can do it like this:

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
SELECT
    columnname
    ,new_value
FROM
    Tablename
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            CAST(columnname as nvarchar(max)) AS columnname_nvarchar
    ) AS CA1
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            PATINDEX('%FPC[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', 
                columnname_nvarchar) AS idx
    ) AS CA2
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            CAST(
                LEFT(columnname_nvarchar, idx) + 
                'newclientnumber' + 
                RIGHT(columnname_nvarchar, LEN(columnname_nvarchar) - idx - 13)
            AS ntext) AS new_value
    ) AS CA3
WHERE columnname LIKE '%FPC[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
)
--SELECT * FROM CTE;
--UPDATE CTE SET columnname = new_value;
```

I used CTE and `CROSS APPLY` to make the query more readable and avoid repeating the expressions. You can put all these expressions into simple `UPDATE`.

I recommend to run the query with uncommented `SELECT * FROM CTE;` line first to check that result is correct. Most likely you'll need to adjust the formula, add or subtract 1 in few places. Once you confirm that calculations are correct, comment `SELECT` and uncomment `UPDATE` line.

---

If your text values can contain several instances of this pattern, then you can run the above `UPDATE` several times until values stop changing (number of affected rows become zero).

Comment: THANK YOU Vladimir! Just for my understanding, what does the '- 13' do? (RIGHT(columnname_nvarchar, LEN(columnname_nvarchar) - idx - 13)

Comment: @user1654659, `13` is the length of the string that you are replacing (`FPC1234567890`). Try to run the query and check the result. You may need to adjust this number by +1 or -1.